# Conditional formatting of cells in a range of columns matching values in a list

Tags: google-sheets

I have a range which spans the columns A to AV and I need to highlight all cells in that range that contain text from a list of elements placed at AY20:AY27.

I know how to highlight matches between two lists. However, I cannot find a working solution applicable for a whole range.

I have also tried to use the "Contains text" option which works if I take each element of the list individually to create a conditional formatting rule. The problem with that method is that if one of the elements of the list is empty then all the range will be highlighted. And the list is manually typed and won't always fill AY20:AY27.

Is there any way to make this conditional formatting work in any way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try clearing formatting from and selecting ColumnsA:AV and Format, Conditional formatting..., Format cells if... **Custom formula is** and:

```
=countif($AY$20:$AY$27,A1)
```

Then select formatting of choice and <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't produce the expected result.